# UITableView is shifting down ~1inch unintentionally when using using sidebar menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a weird bug in my app that uses a sidebar menu with a `UITableView` to list buttons to navigate. When I start my app, [everything looks fine and is in the correct place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyUix.jpg).

Once I make a selection to the respective `viewController, and navigate back to sidebar menu the`UITableView` [is shifted down about 1 inch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWBaN.jpg).

If I press the sidebar menu button to close it, the menu resets and everything works and looks normal. This bug only happens once, once I select an row, navigate back to it, close it, the `UITableView` will be in the correct position until the user hard restarts the app. Any idea whats going on?

Here is my code for the sidebar menu:

```
#import "SideBarViewController.h"

@interface SideBarViewController ()

@end

@implementation SideBarViewController

@synthesize controllerArray, sidebarButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    controllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Search For Games", @"Login", @"Library", nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [controllerArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [controllerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIViewController *selection;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        selection = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:selection animated:YES];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        selection = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:selection animated:YES];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        selection = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LibraryController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:selection animated:YES];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

}
```

I followed the tutorial on the "*Ray Wenderlich*" website for sidebar code.

Also, I've tested other objects, such as buttons and labels and they do not move, its only the `UITableView` that shifts.

Thanks!

Comment: check if the top margin is set to flexible in auto layout constraints.

Comment: @pawan I'll take a look when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: @pawan My margin was not set to flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution! It had to do with the setting for the Navigation controller. Credit due here.

[Container View getting pushed down as if it had a UINavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890192/container-view-getting-pushed-down-as-if-it-had-a-uinavigationbar)

You need to check and see if "Translucent" is checked under the Navigation Bar settings.

Comment: Thanks for this ... just spent two hours scratching my head .... first time in perfect.... then after a modal view transition with an unwind segue --- it would add a noticeable frame shift change. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);` to `viewDidLoad`. This could be a solution if your app is adding insets automatically.

Comment: I had to add this to `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This work, you have to call it once your cell shift down afterward. so it will rearrange.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` in your view controller.
2. Try setting the `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdgeNone`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still shifting down. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with pushing from a UINavigation? It seems to be moving down the width of UINav Title bar...