# UiTableView in tabbarController getting shifted down when using other tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, uitabbarcontroller

have 2 UITableViewControllers and another UIView (3 total) that are owned by a tab bar controller. There is this weird thing happening where sometimes if I go into the the other UITableView (the second image below with the rainbow colors, called search), it will alter the first UITableView, moving all the cells downwards (the correct unaltered version is the third image, the altered version is the first image). When the UITableView gets moved downwards, there is just this empty rectangular space in between the navigation bar and the first able view cell, and nothing is there and you cant even scroll to that part.

The weirdest thing is I cannot replicate it. In other words, I don't know how to force it to happen, only that it happens sometimes when I go into the other tabs and return to the first tab (the UITableView called Featured Debates).

Anybody experienced this before or have any suggestions? Thanks.
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here:The issue had to do with translucency of the navigation controller that owned this particular tab bar controller. You can read more about the issue: [UITableView is shifting down ~1inch unintentionally when using using sidebar menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745963/uitableview-is-shifting-down-1inch-unintentionally-when-using-using-sidebar-men)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check view controllers properties from storyboard. Under attribute inspector, just uncheck Under Top Bars property from view controllers properties. After that update your constraints if using auto layout.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this was not the answer as Under Top Bars was already unchecked