# why gap top of uiviewcontroller in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

[image]

I cannot convince why there is a gap at the top of UIViewController? I have fixed and adjust at size classes but cannot solve it yet.

Comment: kindly attach your view hierarchy as well

Comment: This one helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18890623/696465

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any such issue.

1. Try removing your imageView and set a view with background color to test.
2. Check if your image does not contain the image's canvas size bigger than your actual visible image.