# My UITableView Gets ShiftedDown

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that when first displayed it displays correctly with the first row appearing on top.  When I select a cell another UITableView is presented.  If I used the back button on the UINavigation Bar the original UITableView is shifted down with a blank space between the UINavigation Bar and the UITableView.

I am not using story boards.  I am using XIB files.  I am also using a sliding menu that I got the code for from Ray Wenderlich's web site.

When I slide back the main screen over the first UITableView it goes back to its proper position.  But then when I select an entry again the issue described above appears.

I found another post that seems to provide an answer to the issue.  This post says to make some adjustments like to the translucent settings or the auto-layout settings but doesn't give specifics.

Here is that post: [Container View getting pushed down as if it had a UINavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890192/container-view-getting-pushed-down-as-if-it-had-a-uinavigationbar)

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: Did you try setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

Comment: Hi UditS, I tried adding this to the viewdidload and viewdidappear methods.  It didn't work.  The issue is the UITableView shifts down leaving a blank space between the navigation bar on top and the table view.  Where should this code go?  Thanks, Glenn

Comment: This should go in `viewDidLoad`. If it doesn't work, you can also try other things such as Translucent property of `UINavigationBar` `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` or turning off extended edges below top bar `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

Comment: Hi UditS, that did the trick!  I was putting the statement "self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;" in the viewdidload method, but in the wrong view controller. When I placed it in the view controller that was at the beginning of the stack it worked.  Thank you!  Glenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

in `viewDidLoad`, of the `UIViewController` where you have the shifting table view

Comment: I accepted the up vote. I don't have enough reputation points yet to make a difference it seems. Thanks again for your help.  Oh I just hit accept. Sorry I am new.